# The best way to model a one-to-many relationship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate,
According to the article below it seems that the best way to map relationships is unidirectionally in most of the cases other than special cases like Q and A application where  the number of child entities is limited.

Link -
https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/

Is this correct?? I want to clear my doughts and start my ralationship mappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Q & A application I think we will need bi directional mapping.
For a given Question you need to know of the answers given already.
And for an Answer, you need to know what was the question.

```
@Entity
Class Answer {

 @Id
 @Column("answer_id")
 private Long answerId;

 @JoinColumn("question_id")
 @ManyToOne
 private Question question;

}

@Entity
class Question {

 @Id
 @Column("question_id")
 private Long id;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
 private List<Answer> answers;
}
```

So here the owning entity will be Answer
means Answer table will have the question_id 
Question table wont store answer_id

Answer (score 1):

Unidirectional or bi-directional, it all depends on your requirements.
For example :-
   A and B are two entities : 
   1>A has one-one unidirectional relationship with B, This is a scenario where you do not 
     need/want to load A when you are loading B.
   2>If you want to load A when you are loading B , then you will require One-One bi- 
    directional mapping.